# How can I create a const assignment in a typescript transformer?

Tags: typescript, transformer-model

I can create a variable assignment with this code:

```
ts.createVariableStatement(undefined, 
     [ts.createVariableDeclaration('a', undefined, 
      ts.createStringLiteral('42'))])

/// yields: var a = 42
```

I cannot however create a const assignment. I am quite sure it *should* work like so:

```
ts.createVariableStatement([ts.createModifier(ts.SyntaxKind.ConstKeyword)], 
     [ts.createVariableDeclaration('a', undefined, 
      ts.createStringLiteral('42'))])
```

but this yields an error:

```
[!] Error: Unexpected keyword 'var'
```

an no javascript is emitted due to that error. The error message is very confusing as well.

Comment: What javascript is generated?

Comment: none. I add this to the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
ts.createVariableStatement(
      [],
      ts.createVariableDeclarationList(
        [
          ts.createVariableDeclaration(
            'a',
            undefined,
            ts.createStringLiteral('42'),
          ),
        ],
        ts.NodeFlags.Const,
      ),
    )
```

Based on [this answer](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21357#issuecomment-359810457).